# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.certifi'

Tags: macos, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to pip install the following packages but they all gave me the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.certifi'`
The following packages are the ones that I am trying to install

```
pip install torch
pip install pytorch
pip install tensorflow
pip install google-colab
```

I am using a MacOS and my environment is using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook. I tried to fix this issue but I cannot find any solutions online that works with my case. I am wondering does anyone here knows how to fix this or encountered the same issues before?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your pip version? "pip --version"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade pip with the following command.

```
pip install -U pip
```

If it is upgraded to the latest version already reinstall it using the following commands.
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` to download it, and `python get-pip.py --ignore-installed` to reinstall pip.